# How to upload post on Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook-comments

I want to post on Facebook some text with a link. I am able to do this but the problem is that when I launch the app first time then it will ask for login but after that when I am using again to post on Facebook then neither it will ask for permission or neither I have any option to logout my account and login again with another user.

When I set

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

then it redirect to safari and ask to allow to post on Facebook but after allowing I am not able to post but when I am using

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

then It not take any permission or post on facebook. So I want that every time when user click on post button then it will ask to allow or not or there must be an option to log out or login with another user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For logout functionality add a button on the screen and in its method add the code below:

```
       SHK logoutOfAll];
       [SHKFacebook logout];
       [SHK logoutOfService:@"SHKFacebook"];
```

and this line is ok: `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];`

Dont try and change this.

Comment: Hello, I am not using sharekit. I am using FBDialog.bundle.

Comment: I am not try ever with FBDialog.bundle. But why are you not use share kit. Most easy way to share text & link in social sites...